# Refresh User Control in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 3 user controls in an aspx page in my MVC application. 
i bind data from DB from one controller.

on the selection of "Filter / Status" i want to bind data (refresh) to "List" user control with out refreshing "Filter & Status" user controls.

below are my user controls in aspx page.
please help me how to refresh part of the page/user control.

i have tried by returning only "ListView" View data. but its searching for the other 2 views & throwing exception.

```
          <td>
                <%Html.RenderPartial("Filter", ViewData["FilterView"]); %>
            </td>

            <td valign="top" width="15%">
                <%Html.RenderPartial("Status", this.ViewData["StatusView"]); %>

            </td>
            <td valign="top" width="85%">

                <%Html.RenderPartial("List", this.ViewData["ListingView"]); %>

            </td>
```

Comment: jQuery & ajax an option for you? You could add a controller action that returns JSON and fill the list with it.

Comment: jQuery is bundled with MVC, it's integration (as in any web projects I've seen so far) is almost flawless.

Comment: My Action will be in one user control, i have to bind data in other user control based on the selection in the first user control. how can i use JSON for this?

Answer (score 1):

do sth like this

1. html (aspx page):

> ```
>    <div id="ListingView">
>     <%Html.RenderPartial("List", this.ViewData["ListingView"]); %>
>     </div>
>     ...
>     <input type="button" id="refreshListingView" />
> ```

1. javascript to handle it:

   ```
    $('#refreshListingView').click(function () {
       var selectedStatusId = 'get here proper status id';
       $.ajax({
           url: '/YourController/GetListingView',
           type: "GET",
           data: { "statusId": selectedStatusId },
           success: function (response) {
               $('#ListingView').html(response);
           }
       });
   });
   ```
2. YourController:

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult GetListingView(int statusId)
   {
        ViewData["ListingView"] = your data filtered by statusId or what you want;
       return PartialView("List",ViewData["ListingView"]);
   }
   ```

Instead of ViewData["ListingView"] I would use dedicated model, but it's just an example. It should work.

Comment: If the control and refresh action are truly self-contained (decoupled from the rest of the containing page) you could even have the script and trigger in the control markup too.